# Join 2 or multiple tables from different database in postgres using PHP Laravel 2019

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, join

What is the Laravel syntax to join 2 tables from different databases in postgres?

For example:

```
database1 table column
join
database2 table column
```

Comment: What is your problem here? What you have already done?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

## Configure:

Define the config/database.php multiple databases' connection:

```php
        'pg' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            ...
       ];
        'pg_2' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_ONLINE', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_ONLINE', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_ONLINE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_ONLINE', 'forge'),
       ];
       ...
```

And set connection in Model:

```php
class Model1 extends Model 
{
    protected $connection = 'pg';
}
class Model2 extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'pg_2';
}
```

### Usage:

And you can easily get Eloquent or query builder from different databases:

```php
Model2::join('database1_name.table AS table1', 'table1.id', '=', 'model2.table_id')
       ->where(...)
       ->select('model2.*', 'table1.column')
# OR
\DB::connection('pg_2')->table('model2')
                       ->join('database1_name.table AS table1', 'table1.id', '=', 'model2.table_id')
                       ->where(...)
                       ->select('model2.*', 'table1.column')
```

Comment: can i use the same with DB:: instead of ModelFromDB1?

Comment: @GDP if your table not from the default database, you need to use `DB::connection('your_connection')->`... However, you need to configure the connection in your database.php